# React : data[0].toFixed is not a function. (In 'data[0].toFixed(decimalPlaces)', 'data[0].toFixed' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native, react-native-chart-kit

I want to fetch numerical values through API call and represent them in graph using 'react-native-chart-kit', but its producing error  data[0].toFixed is not a function. How to resolve this error?[click here to view error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCfBa.jpg)

```js
class SecondActivity extends Component {

 constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state={a:"",b:""}
 }

 componentDidMount(){
   this.graph = setInterval( () => this.GetGraph(),1000);
 }

 GetGraph(){
   var jsondata;
  fetch('api here', {
    method: 'GET'
 })
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then((responseJson) => {
   
   this.setState({
       jsondata: responseJson,
       a:responseJson[0].val,
       b:responseJson[1].val,})
   }) 
 .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
 });   } 

  render() {
      if(!this.state.a) {
    return <ActivityIndicator/>
  }
    return (
      <View>
        <LineChart
          data={{
            labels: [
              '1',
              '2', ],
            datasets: [
              {
                data: [
                  this.state.a,
                  this.state.b,                                 
                ],
              },                ],              }}
          width={Dimensions.get('window').width} 
          height={250}
          yAxisLabel="a"
          yAxisInterval={1}/>
      </View>);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `react-native-chart-kit` but since `toFixed()` is a [method on `Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), I suppose `responseJson[0].val` and/or `responseJson[1].val` may contain (some?) other values then numbers.

Depending on the data, a workaround **may** be a conversion to numbers:

```js
this.setState({
    jsondata: responseJson,
    a:responseJson[0].val.map(v => { /* return v converted to number */ },
    b:responseJson[1].val.map(v => { /* return v converted to number */ }
})
```

I won't provide a conversion here. Without knowing the possible values in your data, any proposal could be lossy (or just plain wrong).

Secondly, if the server is expected to send numbers, it should send numbers. This may be a bug, but there may also be a reason for sending numbers, e.g. to be able to submit numbers with high precision or sending fixed point decimals lossless. In this case, you have to be careful how to use these values in JavaScript.

If this is not the solution you should provide the raw JSON response for further inspection.

Comment: the JSON format is as : [{"tran_date":"2020-01-01","val":0},{"tran_date":"2020-01-02","val":999}]

Comment: Is this the content of `responseJson`, or `responseJson[0 (or 1)].val`?

Comment: it's the content of responseJson